# How to do multiple http requests using the same socket connection in java?

Tags: java, sockets

I have laboratory work to make a crawler using BSD socket api, so i need to make multiple http requests to extract all responses, i was trying to do it with single socket connection, but i can get the response only after sending first request header, for other response is empty.
Here is my code, so what are the solutions?:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("fucking-great-advice.ru", 80);

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

    for (int numberAdvice = 1; numberAdvice < 100; numberAdvice++) {
        output.write("GET /advice/" + numberAdvice + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
        output.flush();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int ch = 0;
        while ((ch = input.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) ch);
        }
        String response = sb.toString().split("\r\n\r\n")[1];
        System.out.println(response);
    }

    input.close();
    output.close();
    socket.close();
```

Comment: Have you tried with [keep alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are many problems in your current code:

1. You don't provide the `host` in the header of your request such that you get an error `404`.
2. You keep reading the `InputStream` until you get `-1` which means that you implicitly expect to reach the end of the stream (stream closed) which is not what you want as you try to keep querying the server.
3. You need to add the header `Connection: keep-alive` to indicate the server to avoid closing the connection once answered
4. As this website gives results in chunks, we need to manage it in the code by reading the response line by line and checking for start and end of chunk.

The request is then:

```
output.write(
    String.format(
        "GET /advice/%d HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: fucking-great-advice.ru\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n",
        numberAdvice
    )
);
output.flush();
```

Here is how you can read and display the responses:

```
if (numberAdvice > 1) {
    // Skip inter responses empty line
    input.readLine();
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
boolean started = false;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!started) {
        // Here we check if we reached the end of the header
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            // Here the body starts
            started = true;
            // Skip chunk start
            input.readLine();
        }
        continue;
    }
    if ("0".equals(line)) {
        // Reached chunk end
        break;
    }
    sb.append(line);
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

**NB:** This code is not meant to be optimal or perfect, it only shows the global idea

Comment: i was thinking better about your answer, so it solved my problem, thnx a lot